# Derivation/Explanation of the Freedman-Diaconis Rule

Tags: histogram

Can anyone provide a good derivation of the FD rule? Or explain why it is a good way to define the bin widths of a histogram. Are there any other similar rules and how do they compare?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the Freedman and Diaconis paper where the rule is defined and explained.

Comment: The original paper on this is actually quite accessible (On the Histogram as a Density Estimator: L 2 Theory ): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.650.2473&rep=rep1&type=pdf